# How to implement forgot password in cakephp3.x

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to implement a forgot password function in CakePHP 3.x.
I have created a form that accepts a user's email:

```
<?= $this->Form->create()?>
<div class="form-group">
    <?= $this->Form->input('email', array('class' => 'form-group','autocomplete' => 'off' ,'required' => 'required'))?>
</div>
<div class="form-group">    
    <?= $this->Form->button('Reset Password', array('class' => 'form-group primary'))?>
</div>
<?= $this->Form->end()?>
```

In my controller I'm trying to find the user by the email, if the email exist then a random password will be generated and the password will be updated for that email id:

```
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
use Cake\Auth\DefaultPasswordHasher;

    public function forgotPassword($email = null){

    if($this->request->is('post')) {
         $email = $this->request->data['email'];

         $emails = TableRegistry::get('Users'); 
         $user = $emails->find()->where(['email' => $email ])->first();

         if (!$user) {
             $this->Flash->error(__('No user with that email found.'));
             return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'Users','action' => 'forgotPassword']);

        }else{

                $random = 'a';
                $hasher = new DefaultPasswordHasher();
                $val = $hasher->hash($random);
                $data = $this->Users->password =  $val; 
                if ($this->Users->save($data)) {
                    $this->Flash->success(__('Password changed Succesfully.'));
                     return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'Users','action' => 'forgotPassword']);

                }


        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't actually stated a specific problem/question, but I think I might know what could help.

The whole `DefaultPasswordHasher` bit should be in the UsersEntity file, like in the tutorial: [Blog tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html#authentication-login-and-logout)

With the hashing properly placed in the entity like in the example it will automatically be called as soon as you use either PatchEntity or NewEntity (I think, confirmation please?).

Secondly, the `$this->[model]->save()` function works on entities, not just on data. So you would find the user's entity, patch the entity and then save it:

```
...} else {
$newpass = 'randomstring';
$user = $this->Users->PatchEntity($user, ['password' => $newpass]);

if ($this->Users->save($user)) ...
```